# What is __stdinp?

Tags: c, macos

I am trying to implement a minimal `scanf` on a microkernel seL4, with only the functionality to read a string. Therefore, I am trying to find some clue from reading how [musllibc](https://github.com/seL4/musllibc) implements its `scanf`.

I found out that, in [`stdio.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1081.1.3/include/stdio.h.auto.html), `stdin` is mapped to `__stdinp`:

```
#define stdin   __stdinp
#define stdout  __stdoutp
#define stderr  __stderrp
```

However, I don't understand where `__stdinp` comes from.

For example, [musllibc](https://github.com/seL4/musllibc) implements [`scanf`](https://github.com/seL4/musllibc/blob/sel4/src/stdio/scanf.c) by invoking function `vscanf`. The content for `vscanf.c` is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "libc.h"

int vscanf(const char *restrict fmt, va_list ap)
{
    return vfscanf(stdin, fmt, ap);
}

weak_alias(vscanf,__isoc99_vscanf);
```

Since I am using MacOS, `stdin` here maps to `__stdinp`; this is as far as I can understand. How does the `stdin` work next, and how is it channeled to the actual stdin port to read the standard input?

Comment: Why are you wondering about such implementation details? What problem, if any, is that knowledge supposed to solve? Or is it just plain curiosity? That's fine, but please [edit] your question to tell us that. Or ask about you actual and underlying problem directly.

Comment: Well, evidently `__stdinp` is an `extern FILE *`, as that same header file tells you. But what's your _actual_ question?

Comment: If you need to create C standard `FILE` reading and writing, then do that first. Do it piecewise, one function at a time, with plenty of unit-testing. Then once that works, implementing the higher-level formatted input and output using the streams is simple (well, the reading and writing will be simple).

Comment: On the other hand, if there is no requirement to implement a full C `FILE` stream interface, then skip it, and let your formatted input and output function use the kernels own functions to read and write files. Might want to add a suffix or prefix to the functions, so you know that they are kernel-specific and to not confuse those function with the standard C functions. With that said, while formatted `printf`-like output is very useful for logging in a kernel, formatted input using `scanf` or similar, is *not* very useful. It should be left to the user-space.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! From my understanding `stdin` here is the C `FILE` stream interface. I am curious where it is defined that by simply using `stdin` - `__stdinp` on MacOS that will return the input content from standard input

Comment: Remember that macros in C are really basically replaced with the macro body. So anytime `stdin` is used in the source, that will be replaced by `__stdinp` by the preprocessor. So it seems that `__stdinp` is the actual `FILE *` object being used. You can do that replacement yourself in your code. For example `int main(void) { int d; fscanf(__stdinp, "%d", &d); }` will work just fine. I know that doesn't help understanding what's going on, but what I'm telling you is that the macros are simply a red herring. You need to search for `__stdinp` instead.

Comment: If you already have muslibc then you have the full implementation of the `FILE` structure, and all the functions including `__isoc99_vscanf`.

Comment: We are still missing _WHY_ you want to know about `__stdin`. Obviously this is of type `FILE*` and either is already provided by musl or needs to be provided by you. -- Your next step would be to look in `vfscanf()` to learn more. I'd expect that via `fgetc()` finally `read()` is called for the default device.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong place. Yes in the code there might be `#include <stdio.h>` but you can overwrite the search include paths with `-I` (which musllibc seems to do). Therefore, the actual `stdio.h` file that gets included during compilation is [`stdio.h`](https://github.com/seL4/musllibc/blob/sel4/include/stdio.h) from musllibc and not from apple's own libc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at the wrong place, i.e. you're making the wrong assumption:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
```

It may look like this line includes apple's libc header `stdio.h` but one can change the system header include search paths with `-I` (which musllibc's [`Makefile`](https://github.com/seL4/musllibc/blob/sel4/Makefile.muslc#L49) does).

So the `stdio.h` from apple is completely irrelevant to this piece of code.

If you dig through the musllibc repository you'll find their version of the [`stdio.h`](https://github.com/seL4/musllibc/blob/sel4/include/stdio.h) file which looks like this:

```c
/* ... */
extern FILE *const stdin;
extern FILE *const stdout;
extern FILE *const stderr;

#define stdin  (stdin)
#define stdout (stdout)
#define stderr (stderr)
/* ... */
```

Following the definition you'll find that `FILE *const stdin` is defined in [`/src/stdio/stdin.c`](https://github.com/seL4/musllibc/blob/sel4//src/stdio/stdin.c):

```c
#include "stdio_impl.h"

static unsigned char buf[BUFSIZ+UNGET];
static FILE f = {
    .buf = buf+UNGET,
    .buf_size = sizeof buf-UNGET,
    .fd = 0,
    .flags = F_PERM | F_NOWR,
    .read = __stdio_read,
    .seek = __stdio_seek,
    .close = __stdio_close,
    .lock = -1,
};
FILE *const stdin = &f;
FILE *volatile __stdin_used = &f;
```

As to be expected, `__stdio_read` uses a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to do the reading:

```c
#include "stdio_impl.h"
#include <sys/uio.h>

size_t __stdio_read(FILE *f, unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    struct iovec iov[2] = {
        { .iov_base = buf, .iov_len = len - !!f->buf_size },
        { .iov_base = f->buf, .iov_len = f->buf_size }
    };
    ssize_t cnt;

    // the actual reading takes place here
    // system call takes place here
    cnt = syscall(SYS_readv, f->fd, iov, 2);
    if (cnt <= 0) {
        f->flags |= F_EOF ^ ((F_ERR^F_EOF) & cnt);
        return cnt;
    }
    if (cnt <= iov[0].iov_len) return cnt;
    cnt -= iov[0].iov_len;
    f->rpos = f->buf;
    f->rend = f->buf + cnt;
    if (f->buf_size) buf[len-1] = *f->rpos++;
    return len;
}
```

System calls provide an interface between applications and the underlying kernel.